# htaccess redirect without suffix

Tags: .htaccess

I have a lot of link with the suffix "suc-khoe-doi-song" and they are not working. Such as

http://www.khoemoingay.vn/cong-dong/say-thai-nhieu-tang-nguy-co-dau-tim-suc-khoe-doi-song

How can i redirect them to the same url but without suffix "suc-khoe-doi-song", like below

http://www.khoemoingay.vn/cong-dong/say-thai-nhieu-tang-nguy-co-dau-tim

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a Rewrite rule with the $ symbol, which means a pattern ends with whatever comes before it. The `(.*)` group will capture the desired part of the string and forward it in `$1`

```
RewriteRule (.*)-suc-khoe-doi-song$ /$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: It is not working but i change like this it works 

`code`RewriteRule ^(.*)-suc-khoe-doi-song$ /$1 [R=301,L]`code`

Thanks for your help